# The [planning] tag is being largely misused as [project-planning]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I've been re-tagging many questions with the [planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/planning) tag which are not at all related to the automated planning branch of Artificial Intelligence lately.

It seems to me that by far the most 'wrong' usages have to do with people incorrectly assuming [planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/planning) is  [project-planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-planning). Some [capacity-planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capacity-planning), too, but mostly stuff related to [jira](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira), [scrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrum) or (specially) [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile).

All questions with these tags that are also tagged [planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/planning) could most likely be automatically retagged [project-planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-planning) instead; or maybe [planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/planning) should just be changed into something more descriptive like [automated-planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automated-planning)?

Comment: I suggest [tag:planning-ai]

Comment: omg.  I've not seen so much concentrated offtopic since I burninated software-recommendation.  We don't need to retag, we need to nuke from orbit.

Comment: How exactly does a 'retag request' "goes through"? Are there specialized users who decide such things and perform the nuke from orbit?

Comment: The planing tag is also frequently misused for [hyperion planning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/planning/overview/index.html). Might be worth creating a [hyperion-planning] tag for them. But I'm not an expert in that area.

Answer (score 5):

As of 2023, this tag is just as misused as it was when this was first posted. We should clean it up and rename it.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this today when burninating [ethics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ethics).

[planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/planning) is up to [104 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/planning) and there are a lot of broken windows. I suggest we clean up the tag and possible burninate it.  If there are enough questions that planning and AI need a special tag, I think we should go with [Ben Voigt's idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276744/the-planning-tag-is-being-largely-misused-as-project-planning#comment117147_276744) and create [planning-ai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/planning-ai), otherwise I think [artificial-intelligence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) should work just fine.

Comment: Tag [bold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bold) seems to suffer from a similar problem. It's supposed to be for some Delphi package ... but who reads tag descriptions *anyway*?

Comment: @Jongware It's funny you should mention something like [tag:bold]. The [tag:strong] tag was [recently cleaned up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284042/burninate-strong) for a similar issue.