# Burninate [strong]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [strong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strong) tag has a great excerpt:

> Random tag with no apparent singular meaning.

I see the following usages in my cursory glance:

1. the `<strong>` HTML element,
2. "strong" references,
3. "strong" parameters in Rails,
4. "strong consistency" in databases,
5. a "strong" ownership qualifier (perhaps in Objective-C),

As far as how to replace the tag I see the following:

1. <del>Add an [html-strong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-strong) tag</del> The consensus is to just remove [strong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strong) in favor of [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), rather than adding a specific tag.
2. This appears to be language-agnostic, but I see at least one with [strong-references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strong-references) to balance the [weak-references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak-references) tag.
3. There seems to be a [strong-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strong-parameters) tag for the Rails usage
4. I think using [consistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/consistency) is enough to tell what the question is about.
5. I know very little about Objective-C. I was thinking [ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ownership) would be enough, but that is mixed between this usage of ownership, and file system ownership. <del>Maybe [strong-ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strong-ownership)?</del> Apparently this is the same as [strong-references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strong-references), so I'll just tag that.

I've already retagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22679711/215552) which mysteriously had [strong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strong) as its only tag.

There's not many with this tag, and I'm happy to edit them all myself, but since I've not done this before, I thought I'd ask first.

Shall we remove the [strong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strong) odor of this tag?

Comment: I feel if we added `html-strong` as a tag in place of this, it would push us to making all tags that are related to html elements to start with `html-` for consistency sake. Not saying that is a bad thing though but it's something to think if we actually want to do. I do agree that it's a pretty useless tag and should be burned tho.

Comment: I wondered the same thing. We've already got other `html-` tags for differentiation, like `html-select`, `html-lists`, `html-input`, etc., but, for instance, the tag wiki for `option` advises the use of `html-select` (and the excerpt is "DO NOT USE THIS TAG. It is ambiguous and not helpful."

Comment: Is there anything special about the `<strong>` tag (in HTML) that warrants having a dedicated tag (on SO) for it?  We don't have tags (on SO) for `<em>`, `<code>`, `<small>`, etc either.  I feel that any question about HTML that refers to `<strong>` would be adequately categorized by a more general tag like *text-markup* or even just *html*.  (Disclaimer: I don't participate much in web-related questions.)

Comment: Strong ownership in Objective-C has the same semantics as a strong reference in a garbage-collected language.

Comment: there is no use for an HTML specific "strong" tag, it's too specific and not high enough volume (select, lists, etc maybe justified because they can be pretty complex). I can't imagine anyone ever wanting to browse all the `html-strong` posts...

Comment: The next burnination should be [weak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak)

Comment: @ArtjomB.  should those be retagged to weak-references?

Comment: @eis Not sure. There are a lot of questions in objective-c and C. I don't know how [weak] applies to them.

Comment: Okay, there wasn't many, and I've removed the offending questions. Now, where did I put those marshmallows?

Comment: And... this tag was added to the list of [tags that say "DO NOT USE"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/266086/tags-which-should-not-be-used) which will _surely deter future users_.

Comment: @KevinBrown Totally. Because, luckily, people examine the tag wiki for every tag they use. They definitely don't type sentences into the tag box.

Comment: But then what tag will we use for important questions like, "How you type with boxing gloves on?", or "Can you draw a dragon? I want to see your skills of an artist."

Comment: This just reminds me that the tooltips for tags on Stack Overflow are the most useless tooltips in the history of tooltips.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Burn, baby, burn! We definitely do *not* need anything to talk about the `strong` tag in HTML. I doubt we need a tag for strong references either, as those are just references. If we need a `strong-ownership` synonym, then someone qualified can add one.

Comment: umm... definitely not synonyms, please. Just let it burn.

Answer (score 18):

[image]