# Burninate [inclusion]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [inclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inclusion) tag doesn't seem to be used much. It's also a bit too generic - more specific categorisations (such as [header-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/header-files) for C/C++ or [require-once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/require-once) for PHP) should be used instead.

(Semi-related: We have [require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/require) for Ruby and friends, but we also seem to have the little-used [requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requires) lying around; perhaps this should be the subject of a separate burnination request?)

Comment: So, in other words, you want to... exclude it?

Comment: I just feel that this tag is not [tag:required].

Comment: Looks like we also have an exclusion tag that seems just as muddled as inclusion.  Possibly more prey for Trogdor.

Comment: *includes [inclusion] in Troggy diet*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's my stance, including a couple tags mentioned in the comments as well.

#### Burn these!

- [inclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inclusion) - No wiki tag, no common usage, adds nothing helpful to the question. 1 follower, 55 questions.
- [exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exclusion) - No wiki tag, no common usage, adds nothing helpful to the question. 0 followers, 67 questions.
- [requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requires) - [require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/require) can replace it's appropriate uses AFAIK. No wiki tag, no common usage, adds nothing helpful to the question. 0 followers, 22 questions.

#### Leave this one.

- [required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/required) - This is used for HTML's attribute. The wiki tag wasn't great, but I just updated it to make it more specific. It has 2 followers and 356 questions.

Comment: Do we really need to keep [tag:required]? While the wiki edit gave it a bit of a direction, now there are [~271 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/required+-html+-html5) that are improperly tagged.

Comment: @KevinBrown Wouldn't that mean that we need to retag just those questions in particular?

Comment: That's one possibility, though a post should probably be made on meta as [tag:html-required] might be [preferred for the HTML attribute](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284042/359284).

Comment: Why do we need [tag:required] or [tag:require]? No one would ever want to follow these or ignore them, and no one can be an expert in requiring.

Comment: Adding to the confusion, [there is a difference between `include` and `require`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318144/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-require-in-ruby) in Ruby. Whilst [tag:require] is basically the same as `#include` in C/C++, [tag:include] is used for mixins.

Comment: `require` in my opinion should be remapped to `php-require` as it's a PHP feature.

Comment: ...and a Ruby feature. And a Lua feature.

Comment: [I've created a retag/burnination request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284229/359284) for [tag:require], [tag:requires], and [tag:required]. I'm still in support of burning [tag:inclusion] and [tag:exclusion].

Comment: OK - since we now have a separate question to deal with [tag:require]/[tag:requires]/[tag:required], is there a general consensus that [tag:inclusion] and [tag:exclusion] should be burned?