# Some tags [require] a clean up, others should be [required] to be split up, like [requires]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request

When looking over [the proposal to burninate [inclusion]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284118/359284), comments were made about [require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/require), [requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requires), and [required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/required) existing. **All three of these tags are very broad**, covering a variety of languages and use cases. We should try our best to split these tags up into more specific tags where appropriate.

---

[required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/required) has a tag excerpt of

> Required is an HTML attribute of an input element that forces that the input be supplied.

and the wiki for the tag is

> Required fields are a common form of front-end validation to prevent users from submitting data that is logically incomplete. Though making fields required may not be an end-all validation technique, it is sufficient in a large number of cases.

As [I commented on the other post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284074/burninate-inclusion/284118#comment145547_284118), the HTML `required` attribute, if it deserves a tag, probably should be [html-required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-required) like what [was proposed for [strong]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284042/burninate-strong#comment145106_284042). The problem is that the tag covers many different subjects, covering a variety of languages and situations, which you can tell by [looking at the popular questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/required?sort=votes).

**I propose that we burninate [required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/required) because it is too general,** and using it with extra tags does not help the problem.

---

[requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requires) does not have as many questions as the other tags, but it still suffers from the issue of being very general. It does not have a tag wiki, which is only contributing to the issue.

Most of the questions either fit in with [required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/required) or involve versioning, where one package "requires" another package. **I propose that we either burninate or clarify [requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requires).**

---

[require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/require) is slightly more complex, as while it suffers from the same issue as [required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/required) and [requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requires), in that **it is also very broad**, it *can be helped by using additional tags*. Plenty of languages have "require" keywords, or similar methods for including files, and some of them are even mentioned in the tag wiki. Specifically: JavaScript, PHP, Ruby, and Lua.

PHP also has control of [require-once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/require-once), which could also probably be grouped with whatever happens to the PHP questions in [require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/require). [include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/include) also suffers from the same issue, as so many languages have the keyword.

I'm actually not confident on what we should do with that tag, but perhaps **the tag should be split up into more specialized tags**?

Comment: There was alerady a wiki tag for `required` with the exact same wiki - I just changed the excerpt

Comment: @ZachSaucier My bad, I looked through the history quickly and must have mis-read the dates. I've corrected the original post.

Comment: I would suggest that anything tagged as [tag:required] be re-tagged as [tag:required-field] instead, since that seems to be a more appropriate (if somewhat underused) alternative. It could then be used in conjunction with the [tag:html] tag (or not) depending on the question.

Comment: [tag:required-field] needs a tag wiki, and wouldn't it be better to make them synonyms?

Comment: I'm just wary of `required` being misused due to the ambiguity of its name. Here's a horribly contrived example: A question about SWF files on web pages might be tagged as `flash` `required` because the page *requires* a Flash player to be installed. I'd prefer to do away with ambiguous tag names, rather than relying on (new) users reading their descriptions. If the purpose of a tag is obvious, then the chances of it being unintentionally misused are reduced - The only way that `required-field` could be misused is if the question starts with "I'm working on a farming simulator, and..." :)

Comment: Incidentally, we seem to have [tag:isrequired] as well (zero followers, six questions) - I'm not sure if this would also be relevant to the discussion?