# You are the [weak]est link - goodbye!

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[weak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak) with 118 questions and no tag wiki excerpt

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No, from the tag [weak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak) it's not clear what it refers to, just that something might somehow be weak. And regarding ambiguity, these are some of the usages I see:

- weak self
- weak reference
- weak entity
- weak cipher
- __weak function
- weak variable
- weak encryption
- weak certificate
- weak @IOBOutlet
- weak property
- weak delegate
- weak function
- weak value
- __attribute__ ((weak))
- weak attribute
- "weakness"
- weakref
- WeakMap
- weak symbol
- weak pointer
- weak learner
- weak declaration
- weakObjectsHashTable
- weak enum
- weak macro
- weak source
- weak key
- weak relationship
- weak linking

I might have missed some meanings.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

I wouldn't even call it a concept. In itself [weak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak) is so ambiguous that it's hard to call it on-topic, it needs the appropriate context.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Not really. Without any further information or clues provided, it tells you close to nothing about what the post may be about. It could be about Swift, or encryption, ER diagrams or something else. In some cases I didn't understand why it had been added.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, it just tells you that something is weak, nothing more, and that could be anything. Its usage is all over the place.

**Is it causing harm?**

One possible way a tag can cause harm, according to Shog9, is that it takes the place of better tags. And this seems to be the case.
Some tags that already cover some of the concepts:

- [weak-references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak-references)
- [weak-ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak-ptr)
- [weak-linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak-linking)
- [weakhashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weakhashmap)
- [weakmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weakmap)
- [weak-typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak-typing)
- [weak-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak-events)
- [weakly-typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weakly-typed)
- [weak-entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak-entity)
- [weak-symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak-symbol)

and some more. It's not good when a question is tagged [weak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak) [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reference) instead of [weak-references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak-references), for example ([13 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak+reference)), so people looking for the latter may not find it.

It is relatively often used in [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) questions ([31 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak+swift)) and referring to "weak self" and also with [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) ([19 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak+objective-c)). It might make sense to create more specific tags that are unambiguous, but I'll leave that to SMEs.

---

[What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/11682469)

[Burnination of its antonym strong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284042/11682469)

Comment: Lets get rid of our [weak]ness?

Comment: "Looking forward to the [weak]-end?"

Comment: "This burnination is [weak]"

Comment: "You are the [weak]est link - goodbye!"

Comment: "[weak]ling tags disgust me".

Comment: Pain is just [weak]ness leaving the site?

Comment: I love how everyone immediately jumps to looking for good post titles

Comment: About the actual burnination now :p. I think this tag is the most ambiguous tag in existence. It can also refer to the weak keyword in C, the weak attribute, etc. I think maybe burninating tihs and then creating some new tags would be in order because of how unambiguous this is.

Comment: And how many questions are there with this tag? It might not be that hard to mass-edit all of the questions with this and a related tag

Comment: 118 questions are tagged [tag:weak]

Comment: The burnination for weak will be the Walk of Shame

Answer (score -5):

This has to be the most ambiguous tag in existence. It has so many meanings, even more than the ones that you listed in the question.

Here is the proposal:

- Use the existing [weak-references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak-references) and tag it to all questions which involve a `weak` keyword, or a reference to `weak`. This applies to all languages.
- Create a new tag [weak-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak-function) for all questions that *revolve* around a function called `weak`. A lot of questions seem related to the specific function, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bweak%5D+%22function%22&searchOn=3). This tag has a high chance of being misused.
- Burninate [weak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak) and create any other new tags for major usages of the [weak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak) tag. (If the tag is being used for js libraries, for instance, then create [weak-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak-js)).

Comment: *"Create a new tag `weak-function` for all questions that revolve around a function called `weak`"* - why? We don't tend to have function-specific tags, especially not ones so ambiguous. I think that this tag shouldn't exist either

Comment: @Tomerikoo I tend to agree, but function-specific tags exist everywhere (take for example [tag:nice], which is an actual tag). And in this case I see a lot of questions that revolve specifically around the `weak` function in that language, so it seemed apt to create a tag for that specific usage.

Comment: "*a function called `weak`*" - I don't see any questions about a function with that name. Most are about weakly linked function symbols. They should be tagged [[tag:weak-linking]] or [[tag:weak-symbol]] (and those two probably should be synonymised, but maybe I'm missing a detail there).

Comment: The consensus on meta points into the direction of **not** creating specific function tags. Else we'd need a tag for every function available in every programing language, and with that you could just stop using tags entirely

Comment: @Lino: I would imagine how hard that would be to maintain.