# Burninate: [planning] is not for projects

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There are many users who are confused between [planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/planning) and [project-planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-planning).

- [planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/planning): A branch of artificial intelligence concerned with generating multi-part solutions to problems. Examples include game-playing AI, industrial automation, turn-by-turn directions
- [project-planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-planning): This tags groups questions about techniques, tools, processes and procedures for organize software development tasks

There are many retags in the Suggested Edits that retags [planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/planning) to [project-planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-planning).

Thus, would it be possible to remove [planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/planning) totally and replace it with [planning-ai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/planning-ai) and [project-planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-planning)?

Comment: Do we really need [planning]?

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: Very related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276744/the-planning-tag-is-being-largely-misused-as-project-planning?rq=1

Comment: Management forgot the [planning]

Comment: Related: Here's my [meta q](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320633/the-project-management-clean-up-project) about the [project management] tag

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[planning-ai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/planning-ai) sounds like a good name.

---

[project-planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-planning) sounds like a tag that should be burninated, just as [project-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-management). If someone likes to exhaust their close votes, dig around in these two project tags... there's so much crap to be found. I took a brief look through the posts tagged with them. The posts seem to fall into the following categories:

- How do I configure my IDE/tool?
- Version control, bug databases etc.
- Tool recommendations (off-topic)
- Broad project management discussions (off-topic for many reasons, could possibly be migrated to https://pm.stackexchange.com/)

The on-topic tool etc questions don't benefit from the extra tags. It doesn't make them easier to be found. Seems those tags fill no purpose other than attracting crap.

Comment: +1 The second don't categories isn't really on topic either. Only "how to configure" might* be on topic, and that doesn't really fit this tag.

Comment: I was going to suggest [tag:ai-planning] but I guess [tag:planning-ai] works as well.

Comment: @TylerH The advantage of having planning first is that when people who have already added the ai tag start to type out planning as the next tag, they get planning-ai as suggestion.