# Is Stack Overflow an appropriate website to ask about Project Management issues?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

Are questions regarding project management practices on- or off-topic on Stack Overflow?

There are **1,368** unclosed questions with [project-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-management) however. There are also a number of project-management-related tags out there:

- [agile-project-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile-project-management): 60 unclosed questions
- [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile) 942
- [agile-processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile-processes) 48
- [kanban](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kanban) 126
- [project-planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-planning) 196
- [scrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrum) 512
- <s>[scrummaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrummaster) 0 (burninated)</s>
- [scrumboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrumboard) 29
- [user-stories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-stories) 114
- <s>[retrospectives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retrospectives) 0 (burninated)</s>
- <s>[pmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pmp) 0 (burninated)</s>
- [sprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sprint) 66
- [waterfall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/waterfall) 109
- [task-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/task-management) 20
- [product-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product-management) 23

I want to make sure that I'm not off-base in saying that these questions are off-topic, and/or get some guidance as to how questions with these tags might be on-topic.

Related questions:

- [The [project-management] clean-up project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320633/215552) (this burnination apparently didn't take, as evidenced by the number of unclosed questions now available).
- [Burninate: [planning] is not for projects](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321229/215552) (while there are 50 unclosed questions in [planning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/planning), a quick glance through them indicate they are about AI planning or other programming-related planning topics)

I am aware of the existence of [Project Management](http://pm.stackexchange.com), but also realize that just because something is on-topic elsewhere, doesn't mean it's off-topic here.

Comment: Clearly off-topic, I'd say. As far as I can tell, a reasonable slice of this subject matter is on-topic at Software Engineering -- cf. the [Help Center](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ("software development methods and practices"), as well as [*Should Scrum methodology questions be in pm or programmers stack exchange?*](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6214/101698) and [*Is this site the proper SE site to ask questions about software dev processes?*](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7283/101698).

Comment: These kind of questions should be asked at http://pm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree with project-management being off-topic. But it will be a horrible amount of work to clean that up.

Comment: no, so for programming, not for pm

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It would appear to be off-topic here. The [help center says that questions should cover](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Obviously this is not talking about algorithms, and probably not about tools either. That leaves "a specific programming problem" that must be "practical, answerable", and "unique to software development". But while project management problems can be specific, practical, and answerable, and even occasionally unique to software development, they are not *programming* problems, so they just don't fit here.

Per [duplode's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues#comment448147_343829), [Software Engineering](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Project Management](//pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) seem to be the preferable sites to ask on. As usual, the exact site depends on the exact perspective desired; SE SE is likely to do better at programmer (and former-programmer-promoted-to-manager) perspectives, while PM SE may do a better job at general management perspectives.

Comment: Actually, I would say that "project management" is never "unique to software development", because any and every project will face the same economic problems all project has: cost, time, quality. That you develop software, doesn't make your problem special.

Comment: @Braiam: Meh, just go ahead and -1 because I'm not willing to generalize as sweepingly as some. I'm not going to insist that there definitely are uniquely software PM problems, although I suspect there are; the answer simply assumes that and explains why it doesn't matter anyway.

Answer (score 1):

PM.SE should be the place for such questions.

Before downvotes start to fly, give me 2 minutes to explain:

**A project manager (as a person) is *NOT a must have* in every project**.

**Project management (as a role), on the other hand, *is required***.

The *management* of a project encloses activities such as estimation, optimisation, organization.

With that in mind, *good* developers oftentimes strive to **optimise their teams**, asking questions on how estimations could be better given, how to plan better release cycles, how to have a more productive team. These are management questions. Agile promotes self managed teams. With *self management*, emanating *from the team*.

Being Stack Overflow is a heavy developer-oriented community, I'm aware my answer might not be popular. The purpose of my answer is to have a *single place* where similar questions should be asked, instead of scattered agile questions on Stack Overflow, [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) and PM.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow has a condition that questions that don't fall into it, they are simply outside of the scope:

> - a practical, answerable problem that is **unique to software development**

Stack Overflow is a site dedicated to questions unique to software development. Project managing is never "unique to software development", as any project manager in the software industry will face the same economic problems all project managers have: balancing between cost, time and quality.

Suffixing "for programmers/software developers" doesn't automatically makes the question on topic for SO, and this topic is very broad to limit yourself at only what programmers do.