# Are questions asking about project management features of programming tools on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

Occasionally (especially, for example, in the [kanban](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kanban)), I'll see people ask about project management tools within programming tools. E.g.: [Which is the difference between the swimlanes on Kanban board of the TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643310/which-is-the-difference-between-the-swimlanes-on-kanban-board-of-the-tfs) TFS is primarily a programming tool, but the question isn't really about programming.

Should questions like this go here on SO, on PM SE, on Software Engineering SE, or on Super User?

Comment: Probably PM.se. See a [similar question I asked a while back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343829/215552).

Comment: Duplicate of [Is Stack Overflow an appropriate website to ask about Project Management issues?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues)

Comment: @VladimKotov No, not at all, I'm asking about a very specific edge case.